# How to create windows custom virtual printer to send document to remote server

Tags: windows, printing, driver

I am pretty new to windows development and I want to create a package that installs a virtual printer. This virtual printer when selected during the printing process, sends the file to a remote server (REST API), nothing more, no rendering, no UI.

I tried googling regarding this but couldn't find any good docs or source code on how to create a driver.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please share what you have done so far and read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the Microsoft Printer Driver Samples from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/print).

I think that you might be able to maybe [SampleOpenXPS](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/print/SampleOpenXPS) sample